# Wordpress Plugin Install Using Composer and Custom Repo Path

Tags: wordpress, git, plugins, composer-php

I'm building a wordpress site using Roots/Bedrock with Composer.  Everything has been working great so far, but I'm having a problem installing plugins from Github where the core plugin files are in a subdirectory.

Here's an example:

Plugin package entry

```
  {
  "type": "package",
  "package": {
    "name": "katzwebservices/Gravity-Forms-Salesforce",
    "type": "wordpress-plugin",
    "version": "3.0.6.1",
    "source": {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "git@github.com:katzwebservices/Gravity-Forms-Salesforce.git",
      "reference": "origin/master",
      "package-path": "trunk/"
      },
    "require" : { "composer/installers": "v1.0.12" },
    }
```

This installs the "Trunk" directory into the "Gravity-Forms-Salesforce" directory.

If I move the files in "Trunk" to the "Gravity-Forms-Salesforce" directory, the plugin is recognized.

Is there a way to install only the files in "Trunk" directly into "Gravity-Forms-Salesforce" directory through Composer?  The "package-path" option doesn't seem to do anything.

Thanks!